# Firebase "Uncaught TypeError: myDataRef.push is not a function"

Tags: javascript, php, firebase

I'm making PHP game, which uses Firebase-powered chat. 
I have included code below. Its element of

```
$text = "(...)";
```

(where (...) means the code)

I have a problem, when I click Enter on the input to send the message nothing happens. Chrome shows that

> Uncaught TypeError: myDataRef.push is not a function

but that makes no sense. My code is most copy of the [Firebase Tutorial](http://firebase.com/tutorial), but modified, that input is before the messages, and when new one appears it goes to up, not down.

```
<input type='text' id='messageInput' placeholder='Wiadomość'>
<div id='messagesDiv'></div><br>
<script>
  var myDataRef = new Firebase('https://********.firebaseio.com/').limit(15);
    $('#messageInput').keypress(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
      var name = '".$user->username."';
      var text = $('#messageInput').val();
      myDataRef.".'push'."({name: name, text: text});
      $('#messageInput').val('');
    }
  });
  myDataRef.on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
    var message = snapshot.val();
    displayChatMessage(message.name, message.text);
  });
  myDataRef.on('child_removed', function(snapshot) {
    //do nothing
  });
  function displayChatMessage(name, text) {
    $('<div/>').text(text).prepend($('<em/>').text(name+': ')).prependTo($('#messagesDiv'));
    $('#messagesDiv')[0].scrollTop = $('#messagesDiv')[0].scrollHeight;
  };
</script>
```

I have searched for any answers, but I haven't found anything.

Thanks

Note: the game is available here: [Automaty](http://dominik.drozak.net/pl-pl/automaty), but its in Polish.

Comment: This looks invalid: `myDataRef.".'push'."({name: name, text: text});`. It's probably meant to be `myDataRef.push({name: name, text: text});`

Comment: It does not matter. Its PHP so "test".'test'."test" will be equal to "testtesttest". I think that help is no longer need, because every user can post with someone else nick, by changing source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to write a transaction on a Query object.

```
var myDataRef = new Firebase('https://********.firebaseio.com/').limit(15);
```

The `limit()` returns a [Query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query) object and not a DatabaseReference.

> Instances of Query are obtained by calling startAt(), endAt(), or limit() on a DatabaseReference.

Try:

```
var myDataRef = new Firebase('https://********.firebaseio.com/');
myQuery = myDataRef.limit(15);
// ...
myDataRef.push({name: name, text: text});
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, well... as you can see this question is old and I do not longer need FDB... But you got my accept.

Comment: I thought so, but I had a similar question and discovered yours :)